# Redirect para URL externo com basic authentication em MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou a desenvolver um portal em C# MVC3 e numa dada operação necessito de abrir numa janela à parte um outro portal. Para abrir a página deste novo portal preciso de enviar umas credenciais, visto que este está implementado com basic authentication.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer. Já experimentei no `controller`:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirectUrl);

request.Method = "GET";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

var cred = new NetworkCredential("user1", "pass123");
var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri(redirectUrl), "Basic", cred);

request.Credentials = cache;
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

return Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isto?

Comment: Não podes fazer isso. O melhor que podes fazer é fazer o pedido a esse URI passando as credenciais e devolver a resposta em vez do redirecionamento.

Comment: não tem como setar o cookie e depois abrir a página ?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível , visto que você precisaria gerar o cookie exato para o portal que esta tentando acessar.

Se as credenciais forem as mesmas do seu portal, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
HttpWebRequest req =     (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri); 
// Add the current authentication cookie to the request 
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]; 
Cookie authenticationCookie = new Cookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority); 
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie); 
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Porém acredito que este não seja o seu caso.